# ssh server does not start on lubuntu live image

Tags: usb, lubuntu, ssh, live-usb, sshd

I installed the lubuntu 13.10 32bit iso image with usb-creator-gtk on a USB stick and assigned 2GB of persistent storage to it. That's for a thin client, which does not have any storage of itself at my office and we don't have a way to do net pxe boots.

After I booted the thin client from this USB stick, I installed openssh-server, but it just won't start:

```
$ sudo start ssh
start: Unknown job: ssh
```

Hm, well, why? `dmesg` doesn't show anything and neither does `/var/log/syslog`.

I can manually start `sshd` just fine, **after** I first created the `/var/run/sshd` directory:

```
$ sudo -i
# mkdir /var/run/sshd
# /usr/sbin/sshd
# ps awux | grep sshd
 ... -> shown
# pkill sshd
# start ssh
start: Unknown job: ssh
```

`/etc/init/sshd` exists and has sensible content (compared it to my normal workstation).

Any ideas?

Reinstalling (→ `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server; sudo apt-get install openssh-server`) did not help :(

Comment: Could you add results of `ls -l /etc/init.d/ssh ; ls -l /etc/init/ssh.conf` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To install use it

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

try to restart the service using

```
sudo service ssh restart ## to start /  restart
```

Check the firewall is it blocking the 22 port

```
sudo ufw allow 22 ## allow the 22 port
```

Hopefully, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe init daemon knows nothing about your ssh service: if `initctl list | grep ssh` return nothing, then  try to reload configuration for init manually:

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

then try to start ssh with:

```
sudo start ssh
```

or

```
sudo service ssh start
```